# Call android method from Asp.net code behind over Android WebView

Tags: c#, android, webforms, android-webview

Im using webview from android application .
I want to call a method in android from c# code behind.

```
//In Android app


 void showData(String Name){..}
```

//In C#

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,GetType(),"showData","javascript:Android.showData('"+txtName.Text.Trim()+"')",true);
```

But function is not trigering.
On ButtonClick Event.

Comment: When you're calling the `RegisterClientScriptBlock` from c#? on `page_load() or `on button click?